# .NET valid property names

Tags: .net, properties, naming

Where is the documentation for valid property names in .NET? Obviously things like space, * or & aren't valid in a property name, but where is this documented?

Comment: for extra points, if the spec varies from language to language, what happens if I use the TypeBuilder class to generate a class with properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(VS.71).aspx

From the language spec. Property names are identifiers just like members and functions. Granted, there are standard naming conventions elsewhere that are optional, but greatly encouraged.

Answer (score 8):

You can look the information up for a particular language on the platform, here are a few.

[C# Language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336809.aspx)
[VB Language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms234437.aspx)

More specifically:  [C# Property Declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04(VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

The rules for valid identifiers apply to the properties as well.

Start looking here: [C# Language Specification - 2.4.2 Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf for the C#